# How to override method used in contructor in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

I am very new to Java programming and I am trying to define a hierarchy of classes where the constructor of the base class calls a method that can be overridden in subclasses. Now, I have understood that a constructor can only call class (i.e. static) methods, not instance methods. But static methods cannot be overridden (they are only masked). So the following example prints "1 1" instead of "1 2", as I would like... Is there a simple, elegant way to implement such behaviour ?

```
class A {
    private int data;

    public A(int input) {
        data = computeData(input);
    }

    static private int computeData(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public String toString() { return "" + data;}
}

class B extends A {
    public B(int input) {
        super(input);
    }

    static private int computeData(int i) {
        return 2*i;
    }   
}

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A(1) + " " + new B(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Now, I have understood that a constructor can only call class (i.e. static) methods, not instance methods.` You've been lied to.

Comment: "Now, I have understood that a constructor can only call class (i.e. static) methods," ... you understood wrong.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You beat me by 13 seconds :-p

Comment: A constructor can _can_ call non-final instance methods, but according to Josh Bloch in _Effective Java_, it _shouldn't_. This is because you could have unexpected behavior if those methods are overridden, since the subclasses have access to an object that is only partially constructed.

Comment: All right... I misunderstood. I mistook "shouldn't" for "cannot"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out: `private methods` are not inherited. so in the `B class constructor`, you are calling `super(i)` which uses `computeData method` of class A.

```
class A1 {
    private int data;

    public A1(int input) {
        data = computeData(input);
    }

     protected int computeData(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public String toString() { return "" + data;}
}

class B1 extends A1 {
    public B1(int input) {
         super(input);
    }

     protected int computeData(int i) {
        return 2*i;
    }   
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A1(1) + " " + new B1(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question perfectly. But I understand that calling an instance method in a constructor, although possible (as demonstrated here) is not recommended, as mentioned by gla3dr.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call instance methods from your constructor (and instance methods can be overridden / redefined in subclasses).

However, you must make sure to call the `super()` constructor first.

Answer (score 0):

You can call instance methods in your class constructor.

In `class B`

```
public B(int i) {
  super(i);
}

@Override
protected int computeData(int i) {
    return 2*i;
}
```

In `class A`

```
protected int computeData(int i) {
    return i;
}
```

Comment: this will not work. it will still return the same as what SO posted. because superclass computeData method is private. it is not inherited

Comment: yeah u have to change the definition of super class method also.. u have to make that protected..